# chunked encoding and performance

Tags: http

Will chunked encoding improve the performance of uploading/downloading?

Answer (score 4):

If you know the final complete size upfront, it can only be worse (compared to communicating the Content-Length in the header).

If you do not know, you have no other choice if you want to avoid collecting everything in a (potentially huge) buffer first (which would in fact degrade performance).

Comment: I didn't read your answer carefully enough.  I'm wrong. I deleted my comment.